# Popcap's SexyApp Framework FAQ's etc

Tags: frameworks

What's the best way to get started using Popcap's "SexyApp Framework",  and is it a good idea?

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SexyApp_Framework#PopCap_Games_Framework)

Comment: The fact I have had no answers almost answers the 2nd part of the question!

Comment: There's a Necromancer badge here for someone...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take a (potential) Necromancer badge, even though you've (likely) already found your answer ... or went with `SDL`.

So, the [developer.popcap.com](http://developer.popcap.com/) is still active, although you won't find anything (like, say, docs) there.

Thankfully, you can still get it on **[popcapframework.sourceforge.net](http://popcapframework.sourceforge.net/)**, which has all the installation guides, docs, etc.

It's been more than two years, but, hey, at least you got the answer. :)

Comment: To be honest I had completely forgot about this :-)